# can't connect remote server db2 command line

Tags: db2

i am try to connect another server using db2 command CONNECT TO 192.168.131.16db2admin:25000/SAMPLE USER  db2admin USING Password@123 but remote server not connect Error Display on SQL0104N  An unexpected token "192.168.131.16db2admin:25000/SAMPLE" was found
following "TO".  Expected tokens may include:  "".
SQLSTATE=42601..please give any solution

Comment: You have to CATALOG the remote server first. See https://blog.4loeser.net/2016/03/mom-i-joined-cloud-or-use-old-stuff.html

Comment: You cannot give a connection-string  to the command `db2 connect to ...` . You need to understand that.   Make a choice.  You __either__ have to first use `db2 catalog tcpip node ...` followed by `db2 catalog database  ... at node ...` (after which the `db2 connect to ....`  should work)    __or__  you can completely ignore the CLP and instead use `clpplus` app, which lets you use a connection string.  Study the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to catalog the remote database, you may construct the configuration file on the fly to make it work with the Db2 command line processor.
The script constructs temporary configuration file and uses the corresponding environment variable with this file name saving its previous value and reverting it back after the `db2 connect` command.

**Linux & Unix example**

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Usage: . ./db2connect host:port/dbname USER username [USING password]" >&2
  exit 1
fi

DSN=${1}
CFGFILE=./db2dsdriver.cfg.$$
dbname=${DSN#*/}
hp=${DSN%/*}
host=${hp%:*}
port=${hp#*:}

cat > ${CFGFILE} <<EOF
<configuration>
  <dsncollection>
    <dsn alias="${dbname}" name="${dbname}" host="${host}" port="${port}"/>
  </dsncollection>
  <databases>
    <database name="${dbname}" host="${host}" port="${port}"/>
  </databases>
</configuration>
EOF

cfg_bkp=${DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH}
export DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH=${CFGFILE}
shift
db2 connect to ${dbname} "$@"
export DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH=${cfg_bkp}
rm -f ${CFGFILE}
```

*Usage:*

```
. ./db2connect 192.168.131.16:25000/SAMPLE USER db2admin USING Password@123
```

Don't remove space between the 1-st dot and the path to this executable file.

**Windows example:**

```
@echo off

if [%1] == [] (
  echo Usage: %~nx0 host:port/dbname USER username [USING password]
  goto :eof
)

set cfg_bkp=%DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH%
set CFGFILE=.\db2dsdriver.cfg.tmp
set DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH=%CFGFILE%

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:/" %%i in ('echo %1') do (
  set host=%%i
  set port=%%j
  set dbname=%%k
)

if exist %CFGFILE% del %CFGFILE%
db2cli writecfg add -database %dbname% -host %host% -port %port% > nul
db2cli writecfg add -dsn %dbname% -database %dbname% -host %host% -port %port% > nul

db2 terminate
db2 connect to %dbname% %2 %3 %4 %5
set DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH=%cfg_bkp%
del %CFGFILE%
```

*Usage:*

```
db2connect.bat 192.168.131.16:25000/SAMPLE USER db2admin USING 'Password@123'
```

Comment: its not working window command line processer .Error like db2connect 192.168.131.16:25000/SAMPLE USER db2admin USING Password@123 please help

Comment: You need Windows example, If I got you right. If yes, then look at the updated answer.